# helpme for TimePickerDialog and date now

Tags: java, android

I am using a button which shows the hour and minute of the team with this method

```
 private void obtenerFechaActual() {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        }

            btnSelectTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // Show the TimePickerDialog
obtenerFechaActual();
                             showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

                        }
                    });
            @Override
            protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
                 case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                  return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                  mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);
              }
               return null;
         }

            private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
             new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
          public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int min) {
                                                   hour = hourOfDay;
                                                   minute = min;
                                                   btnSelectTime.setText("Time selected :"+hour+"-"+minute);
                                                 }
                                           };
```

It does well, but every time I press the button,it keeps the minutes and the date of the first click of the button. The idea is that every time you click the button, it displays the current time and date.

Comment: It looks like your question/problem is not a problem but the indicator of what is missing. I do not see you setting the dialog more than the time its created. That is why when you open the dialog the second time it still has the value from the last time it was open. You will need to change that dialog before displaying when you click on that button

Comment: You get the current time at `obtenerFechaActual()`, but where do you call this method?

Comment: Thank you. for their comments. and add the motodo at the click of button .. it would fail to add me? thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this method:

```
@Override
                           protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
                               switch (id) {
                                   case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                                       ((TimePickerDialog) dialog).updateTime(mHour, mMinute);
                                       break;
                                   case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                                       ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                                       break;
                               }
                           }
```